# why do the event(webkitTransitionEnd) fire three times

Tags: javascript, css

My animation changes only one attribution(font-size),
but the event fires triple.Why???

css:

```
.fadein{
  font-size:2em;
  -webkit-transition:all 3s ease-in-out;
}
```

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("button").on('click',function(){
    $("div p").eq(0).addClass("fadein").on('webkitTransitionEnd',function(e){
    console.log(e);
    });
  });
});
```

html:

```
<div>
<p>toggle paragraph</p>
</div>
<button>toggle</button>
```

http://codepen.io/ShawnHuang/pen/LIlvr

Comment: Other than inside document/window handlers, don't put event handlers inside event handlers. Every time you click the button, a new handler for the `div p` is added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does seem to be animating 3 properties: `margin-top`, `font-size` and `margin-bottom`:

```
var propertyName = e.propertyName || e.originalEvent.propertyName;
console.log(propertyName);
```

See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Fwfty

**Edit**

Getting all the properties is a bit more tricky. I worked out an example at http://jsfiddle.net/ZD2fY/1/:

```
$.fn.onWebkitTransitionEnd = function(callback) {
  var $this = this;
  var properties = [];
  var events = [];
  var onFinished = function() {
    if (callback) {
      callback(properties, events);
    }
    $this.off('webkitTransitionEnd', onWebkitTransitionEnd);
  };
  var finishTimeout = null;
  var onWebkitTransitionEnd = function(e) {
      var propertyName = e.propertyName || e.originalEvent.propertyName;
      properties.push(propertyName);
      events.push(e);
      clearTimeout(finishTimeout);
      finishTimeout = setTimeout(onFinished, 0);
  };
  $this.on('webkitTransitionEnd', onWebkitTransitionEnd);
};
```

Then you would call it as follows:

```
$("div p").eq(0).addClass("fadein").onWebkitTransitionEnd(function(properties, events) {
  console.log(properties, events);
});
```

Comment: You are right. May I ask you how do you find the other attributes?

Comment: I got it. Your detailed explanation is very useful.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it like this

```
  var property = 0;
  $("button").on('click',function(){
    $("div p").eq(0).addClass("fadein").on('webkitTransitionEnd',function(e){
       if( property === 0 ) {
          property++;
          console.log(e);
       }
    });
  });
```

or you could use jQuery's `one();` which will remove the event listener when the event has triggered

```
  $("button").on('click',function(){
    $("div p").eq(0).addClass("fadein").one('webkitTransitionEnd',function(e){
       console.log(e);
    });
  });
```

This happens because you have a transition on 3 properties of the element

or you could simply do this

```
 transition: font-size 300ms ease-in-out;
```

Comment: he may use simply .one() instead of counting how many times the callback runs